# Rails - How do I implement client-side validation for uniqueness?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation

I have a building model that consists of many blocks.  When a user creates a new block, the name of the block cannot match the name of any other of the blocks associated with that building.  I have figured out how to validate this on the backend, but I would also like to provide client-side validation to inform the user that the name is already in use by another block.  It seems like this will require AJAX to pull off, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to link AJAX to a controller method.  Here is what I have so far:

**Blocks/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@block, :remote => true, :html => { 'data-controller-name' => controller_name.singularize }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :building_id %>
  …
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => "required" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "required", :placeholder => "Untitled block" %>
  </div>
```

**Blocks.js**

```
$('#block_name').blur(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'blocks/check_name',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#block_name').removeClass('error')
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#block_name").addClass('error')
    }
  });
});
```

**Routes.rb**

```
"/blocks/check_name" => "blocks#check_name"
```

**blocks_controller.rb**

```
def check_name
  @building = Building.find(params[:block][:building_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    Format.json { render :json => @building.block_name_available(params[:block][:name]) }
  end
end
```

**Building.rb**

```
def block_name_available(name)
  @block = Block.where(:building_id => self.id, :name => name)
  Return @block.nil?
end
```

If there's a better way to go about this, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy you could use with JavaScript would be to place a submit listener on your form, and call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting. You could then make one ajax request that checks for uniqueness, with both success and error callbacks: on success, submit the form as normal, but on error, notify the user however you'd like that the block name must be unique.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to link the ajax request to my controller.

Comment: The URL that you send the ajax request to will depend on the route that corresponds to the appropriate controller action you'd like it to trigger.

Comment: so, I just need to do: $.ajax({ url: "/blocks/check_name" }) in the blocks.js blur function?  How does the controller know what the field input text is?

Answer (score 0):

Try `:validate => true` in the form_for block.